# How to set the background color of an element in my case

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a `bootstrap accordion` for my app. I also have background color in its parent element. My problem is that when I expand my `accordions`, it extends the height of my page and the background color doesn't cover the extended area.

**my html**

```
<div id='wrapper>
<accordion id='accordion' close-others="false">
    <accordion-group>
        <accordion-heading >
            <h2 class='title'>Title 1</h2>
        </accordion-heading>
        <div id="first" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            //contents...
        </div>
    </accordion-group>
  //I have 5 to 6 accordion group. 
</accordion>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
//I used height:100% and it looks fine when the page first loaded but not after //user //expand all the accordion.

#wrapper{
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;  
    display: block;
}
```

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: make a fiddle for your problem so people can work on it.

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the #wrapper.  Sounds like there might be a float that is not being contained.  Or, adding a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` *after* the accordion.

Comment: Also you have some odd HTML elements in there. Generally it's not a good idea to make up your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) I noticed you could catch the event `shown.bs.collapse` which

> is fired when a collapse element has been made visible to the user
>   (**will wait for CSS transitions to complete**).

So you could try something like:

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
    document.getElementById('wrapper').style.backgroundColor="red";
})
```

Edit: if that does not work try `show.bs.collapse`